# JavaFx HtmlEditor wrong height scaling

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, html-editor

I'm trying to increase the height of my HtmlEditior in a JavaFX application. If I change it with the preferedSize() Methode, the node rescales to the desired height but I can't enter text into the new space. Does anyone know where I've made a mistake?

Code:

```
VBox root = new VBox();
HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
editor.setPrefHeight(1000);
root.getChildren().add(editor);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

[My current gui (external link to imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkL29.png)

In this picture, you can see a large white space. This is the area where I want to write text.

Comment: Change the size of your `VBox root`, as well.

Comment: ok, I've tried the following:
root.setMinHeight(1000);
     root.setPrefHeight(1000);root.setMaxHeight(1000);
Nothing has changed.